# JQuery: scroll event fires only once

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to work on current value fo `scrollTop`, so i wanted to fire event every time user position changes on page.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

However this event fires only once, when page is loaded. It does not react to page scrolling. I triend to put code inside document ready or just inside script tags on end of body.

Surprisingly when i run this code from firefox developers scratchpad, it works fine.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in a snippet ?

Comment: *"However this event fires only once, when page is loaded."* No, it happens whenever the window scrolls: http://jsfiddle.net/59acy239/ Something *else* is going on in your code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Turns out it was jquery mobile fault. I wonder if there is a way to use scroll event along with this lib..

Comment: Actually i think i will stick to this event: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_scroll.asp It also produces less unwanted results that vanilla js scroll.